# What is the marginal effect when there is interaction in a regression model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, marginal-effect

I have data which has experience(in months), `genderMale`, and `exp*genderMale` (interaction).

My question is: What's the marginal effect of `exp` in the case of a male with 80 months of experience?

So since this is marginal effect, I believe the 80 months is information that we do not need, since the marginal effect is the same whether that's 80 months or 2.

But now my question is: is the beta value for `exp*genderMale` the marginal effect in this case? Or will I have to do some calculations with the marginal effects of `exp` and `genderMale`? The model is linear.

Answer (score 1):

As you surmised the marginal effect of `exp` is no longer the coefficient. To understand why you need to look at the definition of the marginal effect. Suppose we have the model,

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_1 X_2+u$$

Let $X_1$ represent `exp` and $X_2$ represent `genderMale`. The marginal effect is defined as,

$$\frac{dY}{dX_1}=\beta_1 + \beta_3 X_2$$

This tells us that the marginal effect will depend on the level of $X_2$ or in this case `genderMale`.

For more details I suggest you take a look at Ch. 2 of [Wooldridge's Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/econometric-analysis-cross-section-and-panel-data-second-edition).

Comment: Thank you very much! So if we know that male is 1 and female is 0, then the marginal effect will be B1+B3, since X2 (male) will be 1 right?
I will check that chapter out! @Ariel

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Ariel